# What assembly does XmlDocument live in, and how do I use it?

Tags: c#, .net, xmldocument, system.xml

I have the following code:

```
using System.Xml;
namespace MyApp {
  public class Foo : IBar {
    public void SomeCallback(object sender, CallbackEventArgs e) {
      string s = e.Result;
      System.Xml.XmlDocument xml;  // <-- Error CS0234.
      ...
```

This results in `error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'XmlDocument' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Xml' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

I have verified that System.Xml is included under "References" in Solution Explorer.  It's listed as using 2.0.x.x, but that should be fine since the class [allegedly existed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28VS.80%29.aspx) then?

I'm not well versed in .net development, so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Yes.  According to the Properties view the assembly's path is: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone\System.Xml.dll`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comment you posted to your question it looks like you are building a Silverlight application.  The type `XmlDocument` is not included in the Silverlight version of the framework.  The recommended alternative is `XDocument`

Here is a tutorial page on using XML in a Silverlight application

- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189074(VS.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189074%28VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Huh.  Well, that does seem to be the case.  Okay, well, it looks like `XDocument` has similar functionality... so, fine.  But that was totally unexpected.  It would be nice if that were actually in the documentation for the class.

Comment: @jeff: it kinda _is_ documented, in a way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml%28v=VS.95%29.aspx